# Differences between select @var=column1 from table1 & select top 1 column1 from table1

Tags: sql-server-2005

In sql server 2005

differences between `select @var=column1 from table1` & `select top 1 column1 from table1`

I have a problem with a view that has a column in select statement at this model

```
select column0, fn(column0) as col from table2
```

that `fn` return `select @var=column1 from table1 where table1.column3=@inputid`

I replace it with this

```
select 
    column0, 
    (select top 1 column1 from table1 where table1.id = table2.column0) as col 
from  table2
```

but result is not same as previous

and using order by in

```
select top 1 column1 from table1 where table1.id = table2.column0
```

has no effect too

I need to know why can I change

```
 select top 1 column1 from table1 where table1.id = table2.column0
```

that has same result as

```
 select @var=column1 from table1 where table1.column3 = @inputid
```

Answer (score 1):

When Sql Server compiles a query, It doesn't compiles Scalar valued function. So you can never know which result will come from Table valued function. Moreover scalar valued function results in relatively bad performance when compared to inline query or table valued functions.
Since **ORDER BY** gets executed after TOP in case of UNION. So I doubt this case is getting applied. Can you paste the execution plan of query

Order of execution of query

```
1. FROM, JOIN, APPLY and ON
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. SELECT
6. ORDER BY
7. TOP
8. FOR XML
```

When using UNION, Order of execution changes slightly

```
1. FROM, JOIN, APPLY and ON
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. TOP
5. UNION and SELECT
6. ORDER BY
8. FOR XML
```